# What is the hidden passcode?

Tags: cipher, visual

The passcode is hidden in these sequences of numbers. Can you find what it is?
[image: Out of order]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the pass code is

> random

Because

> from binary to text through the portal, the binary codes spell out ARNODM when rearanged spell RANDOM.

Answer (score 7):

Taking the binary substrings in

> rainbow order

and converting them to text yields

> random